# An iframe tab code that was working now shows a blank screen

Tags: sdk, tabs, facebook-iframe

I'm making some fanpages.

I have a code that show an image to the user before liking the page, and another image or content after liking the page.

I created several pages with this code and all of them worked fine.

but about 5 days ago, I created one with the same code, and it just showed the "after like" content, even when I haven't liked the page.

and today, I created a new one, and it just shows a blank page. neither the after or the before.

I've checked on the previous fanpages and those are still working, so it's just the new pages that aren't working.

they'r using the facebook php sdk

the procedure I use is:
* upload files to my server
* create a new app
* add urls for page tab (both normal and secure url)
* add app to my page

is someone having the same issue?

does someone know why is that problem and how it can be solved?

thanks,
Abraham

Answer (score 0):

if you have php errors turned off, and you throw a fatal php error before any html output, you might also see a blank screen.

Try uploading a dummy file with some simple text as your main app page, and see if it works.
If so, try tracking down any error that might prevent the page from rendering.

To get output on php errors, add this to the top of your page:
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>